# Adding/removing a PRINT statement changes variables

Tags: fortran

I have some experience writing fortran codes but I have never seen something like this.

I am using a large HPC code (~10K lines) in which I am modifying a subroutine. I used print statements to verify that everything was done correctly and debug if necessary. When I run my code with the last `PRINT` statement I used, the code is giving me real numbers everywhere. Once I comment this last `PRINT` statement, the code is giving me `NaN` is some of my variables. Since my code is too big, I obviously can't post it here, but I'll post the `PRINT` statement:

```
PRINT*, "outletBC up1    ", SUM(ABS(up(nptsx,:,:)))
```

where `up` is some velocity array.

**QUESTION:**

How is that possible? How can a `PRINT` statement possibly affect any variable?

Comment: this is indicative of a bug elsewhere in the code, likely related to accesing an array out of bounds. try turning on bounds checking

Comment: Like @agentp says.  Also check procedure calls match dummy and actual arguments correctly.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I ran my code with the multiple debug flags ifort has available. I fixed all errors (some were out of bounds array access), but the error persists.
I'll keep debugging the code but I was honestly more interested about understanding how can a print statement have any effect on anything else in the code.

Comment: What agentp and Mark said. Also check uninitialized variables. I've had this happen before. If things are shady somewhere else in the code, a print statement may push things around in memory leading to unexpected behavior. Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug

Comment: Similar post on [tag:c++] about an [inifinte loop heisenbug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722647/infinite-loop-heisenbug-it-exits-if-i-add-a-printout)

Comment: @kvantour We have plenty of Fortran examples here. Just on the right to **Related**. (I hope they all don't need the heisenbug tag now...)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is indicative of some other errors in the code (e.g. memory corruption). I am not sure what debug flags you used. However, try compilation flag "-check all" (for intel fortran compiler). This flag checks for multiple possible errors. For more details, you can refer to **https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/f/8/5/8/0/6366-ifort.txt**

Comment: *"I ran my code with the multiple debug flags ifort has available."* I think this is more a comment than an answer and does not bring anything new over the existing commenrs.